# Why is there no IndexError thrown when length of list is smaller than the index used in return statement?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def top_three_new(input_list):
    return sorted(input_list, reverse=True)[:100]
print(top_three_new([2, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

[:100] does not mean that it will return exactly the 100th element. 
[:n] returns the n items from last. If there is less than n items it simply returns all.